# Hazelcast - How to understand if Imap.unlock operation is successful or not?

Tags: locking, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We are using IMap locks in our application. From a thread that is guaranteed to  acquire the IMap lock for the key (this is of type String) we use the below snippet for unlock:

```
        boolean isUnlockSuccess = false;
        try {
            distributedLocksMap.unlock(key);
            isUnlockSuccess = true;
        } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
            // current thread does not hold the lock
            logger.warn(String.format("[%d] Unlock failed for key: %s because current thread does not hold the lock! distributedLocksMapName: %s",
                                      threadId,
                                      key,
                                      distributedLocksMapName), e);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(String.format("[%d] Error occured in unlock for key: %s ! Key could not be unlocked! distributedLocksMapName: %s",
                                       threadId,
                                       key,
                                       distributedLocksMapName), ex);
            }
```

Our assumption is that if there is no exception from

```
distributedLocksMap.unlock(key);
```

call, the lock is released.

Firstly, is this assumption true? There is no boolean returning method related to unlock , and we can see that if a thread that is not owner of the lock calls above method, IllegalMonitorStateException  is thrown.

Secondly, from our log traces, even the above method call completes without error, we **intermittently** see that  the lock is not released.. We could not find any reason how this could happen...

In fact our use case is simple :

1) to try to get lock

2) If the lock ıs successfull perform a long runnıng operatıon

3) unlock usıng the above snıppet.

But sometimes the lock seems to be hold even after the successful unlock call.

As I said this is an intermittent problem and I can not provide a sample test code that reproduces problem  .

Any suggestions?

Regards

Comment: What is your Hazelcast version?

Comment: Hı noctarius.  We are using version 3.6

Comment: Any reason you're still on 3.6? There were plenty of fixed since it's release. Can you please try with 3.8.x and see if the issue still persists?

Comment: If  fixes regarding this lock/unlock issue is done surely we can upgrade it. Regarding my first subquestion is it ok to assume lock is released If unlock method doesn't not throw an exception?

Comment: Hazelcast locks are based on standard j.u.c.locks APIs, so a hazelcastLock.unlock is not supposed to return anything and by design, unlock() releases the lock if/when invoked. As has been suggested earlier, you should try latest version if you are experiencing issues with standard operations. ILock was reengineered in 3.7 and further improved in 3.8.

Comment: In case you still have issues with the latest version, please open a bug report on github and provide further details + logs if possible :)

Comment: @wildnez thanx. We will use the latest available versıon. But just to remind you we are using IMap.lock not ILock.lock. Are these enhancements   also done for  IMap? Reason we are using IMap instead of ILock is because it is advised by hazelcast developers.  https://blog.hazelcast.com/pro-tip-imap-lock-or-ilock-lock/ ,Regards

Comment: IMap.unlock should also follow standard locking/unlocking principles. If you see issues with latest version, feel free to open a bug report on github as suggested by @noctarius